# CUDA - atomicAdd(float) does not add very small values

Tags: cuda

When I use `float atomicAdd(float *address, float val)` to add a float value smaller than approx. `1e-39` to `0`, the addition does not work, and the value at `address` remains 0.

Here is the simplest code:

```
__device__ float test[6] = {0};
__global__ void testKernel() {
    float addit = sinf(1e-20);
    atomicAdd(&test[0], addit);
    test[1] += addit;
    addit = sinf(1e-37);
    atomicAdd(&test[2], addit);
    test[3] += addit;
    addit = sinf(1e-40);
    atomicAdd(&test[4], addit);
    test[5] += addit;
}
```

When I run the code above as `testKernel<<<1, 1>>>();` and stop with the debugger I see:

```
test    0x42697800
    [0] 9.9999997e-21
    [1] 9.9999997e-21
    [2] 9.9999999e-38
    [3] 9.9999999e-38
    [4] 0            
    [5] 9.9999461e-41
```

Notice the difference between test[4] and test[5]. Both did the same thing, yet the simple addition worked, and the atomic one did nothing at all.
What am I missing here?

Update: System info: CUDA 5.5.20, NVidia Titan card, Driver 331.82, Windows 7x64, Nsight 3.2.1.13309.

Comment: `1e-40` is a denormal number for single precision floating point format, and is out of precision range of `float` data type. Most probably the compiler is flushing it to zero. Also, if kernel is launched on multiple threads, the `+=` operation on same memory location will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @sgar91: There is only 1 thread running. The compiler doesn't flush it to 0 in the second case so there is no reason for it to flush it down in the first case. Also, this is a minimal code example, which was motivated by a much more complicated piece of code in which addit was assigned as a result of a complicated dynamic numerical integration, so the compiler couldn't flush it.

Comment: @sgar91: To prevent possible compiler optimization I changed the assignment to addit to be addit = sinf(value) instead of addit = value.

Comment: There is not only 1 thread running. A whole warp is running ie 32 threads.

Comment: @Michael: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#simt-architecture

"The threads of a warp that are on that warp's current execution path are called the active threads, whereas threads not on the current path are inactive (**disabled**). Threads can be inactive because they have exited earlier than other threads of their warp, or because they are on a different branch path than the branch path currently executed by the warp, **or because they are the last threads of a block whose number of threads is not a multiple of the warp size**."

Comment: You need to think in term of `epsilon`. 1e-39 is smaller than the epsilon hence it will be treated as `ZERO`. This has nothing to do with cuda its just normal behaviour in `C`. [More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`atomicAdd` is a special instruction that does not necessarily obey the same flush and rounding behaviors that you might get if you specify for example `-ftz=true` or `-ftz=false` on other floating point operations (e.g. ordinary fp add)

As documented in the [PTX ISA manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-atom):

> The floating-point operation .add is a single-precision, 32-bit operation. atom.add.f32 rounds to nearest even and flushes subnormal inputs and results to sign-preserving zero.

So even though ordinary floating point add should not flush denormals to zero if you specify `-ftz=false` (which is the default, I believe, for `nvcc`), the floating point atomic add operation *to global memory* will flush to zero (always).